# How can I install Redhat OpenJDK 11 on CentOS 7+?

Tags: java, centos, redhat, redhat-openjdk, java-11

As per the **Oracle OpenJDK** policy, there will not have any LTS support anymore, but Redhat OpenJDK will continue to have LTS support so far we have seen. Our current application was based on **CentOS 7** and **Oracle JDK-8** and wants to migrate some sort of free JDK-11 distributions with LTS support for our production server.

*If you guys have any other alternative solution, please let me know.*

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to install OpenJDK11(LTS) with the below command:

```
sudo yum install java-11-openjdk-devel
```

I have tried this on CentOS 7 and it works.

Comment: Slightly related: in order to uninstall previously installed java version you can do

`rpm -qa | grep jdk`

and then (replace xyz with the packages returned by the previous command)

`sudo rpm -e xyz`